# Web.xml configuration replaced with Anotations for LoadOnStartup

Tags: tomcat, annotations, servlet-3.0

Spec
**Tomcat 8.0.20, O/s : win 7, Java : 1.8**

1) Servlet StartServletInit extends HttpServlet

2) StartServletInit has **ONLY 1 method** "public void init(ServletConfig 
   config)" which reads a "properties file" in classpath  and prints on 
   console the Injected key/value pairs on console.

3) Web.xml has heading entry as follows

```
version="3.1" 
  **metadata-complete="false"**  
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
```

3) Web.xml has Load on startup as

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>StartServletInit</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.web.init.StartServletInit</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

O/p : Executes perfectly and prints on console . ===> **:)**

*Problem*

Annotation  [ Commented the web.xml's loadOnStartup & annotated the code ]
"@WebServlet(name = "StartServletInit",loadOnStartup = 1)

O/p : Does NOT - print the key/value on to console. ===> **:(**

Comment: Why the double asterisk in web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can mix web.xml config and annotations for the same servlet. You can use web.xml or annotations, but not both.

Try completely removing the servlet definition and the servlet mapping from web.xml and put the value of the servlet mapping's url-pattern in the annotation as the "value" attribute. The servlet name is not really useful when using annotations.

Example:

```
@WebServlet(value="/your_url_pattern", loadOnStartup=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is to set loadOnStartup to '0', which means to load the servlet eagerly.

Better use a ServletContextListener, if you want to run code at startup. Thats what it is made for, while a servlet is listening to request most of the time:

```
@WebListener
public class BootListener implements ServletContextListener {

 @Override
 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
  // handle app start ...
 }

 @Override
 public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
  // handle app stop ...
 }
}
```

Don't mix up annotation and web.xml declaration, use either one of them. metadata-complete="false" will tell the servlet container to scan the classpath for annotations. This might or might not work in different environments, while a static entry in web.xml will always work.